# Countable and uncountable sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a) Show that $\left \{ n^{2}+m^{2}:n,m\in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ is countable.

b) Show that $\left \{ x\in \mathbb{R}:x(x-2)<0 \right \}$ is uncountable.

**My answers:**

a) Is it possible to define function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be given by $f(n,m)\mapsto n^{2}+m^{2}$? How then would I show that it is bijective such that the set is countable i.e. $\#\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}=\#\mathbb{N}$? I mean, is there not a simpler way to show it?

b) The set is equivalent to $A:=(0,2)$. We have the maps $(0,1)\overset{f}\to A\overset{g}\to\mathbb{N}$. Consider, for example, the bijective map $f:(0,1)\to A$ given by $f(x)=2x$, then $\#(0,1)=\#A$. If the map $g:(0,2)\to\mathbb{N}$ is bijective, then the map $f\circ g:(0,1)\to\mathbb{N}$ would be bijective too. Since it's a contradiction because $\#(0,1)\neq\#\mathbb{N}$, then we conclude that $(0,2)$ is uncountable. Is it correct?

Comment: (a) Your function isn't bijective ($(f(m,n)=f(n,m))$ for $n\ne m$), but surjective is enough IF you *know* that $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ is countable. (b) is correct IF you *know* that $(0,1)$ is uncountable.

Comment: Both questions have been asked before. The first one has been asked recently at least once, the question about intervals have been asked infinitely many times before.

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia:  but has it been asked an *uncountable* infinity of times? ;-)

Comment: @Robert: Obviously, because if you'll try to make a list of these questions you'll always find out that you've missed at least one of them. Cantor's diagonal in the works.

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia:  applied set theory; very nice indeed!

Answer (score 0):

A:  You have a surjection,  from a countable set to your space, which is all you need to prove countability.
you 
For part B,  you have an interval contained in the set,  which is uncountable, correct.